# Migrating from IHostingEnvironment to IWebHostEnvironment

Tags: f#, f#-giraffe

I have this:

```
let configureApp (app : IApplicationBuilder) =
    let env = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>()
    (match env.IsDevelopment() with
    | true  -> app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()
    | false -> app.UseGiraffeErrorHandler errorHandler)
```

And when I tried to migrate, I get the error:

```
let configureApp (app : IApplicationBuilder) =
    let env = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>()
    (match env. with
```

I do not know what I should change in this code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingenvironmentextensions.isdevelopment?view=aspnetcore-2.2), you need to make sure that you have the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` open.